# Images in applets

Tags: java, japplet

i wrote this code for showing some simple picture on the applet screen, but the picture doesnt show untill i resize the applet window, what can i do to overcome it?

```
public class Test extends JApplet {
    public void init () {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }
    public void start() {
    }
    public void createGUI() {
        getContentPane().add(new GUIThing(getImage(getCodeBase(), "gladiator.gif")));
    }
}

public class GUIThing extends JPanel {
    Image image;
    public GUIThing(Image i2) {
        image=i2;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(image,100,100,100, 100, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `repaint();` to the end of `createGUI()`?

Comment: tried that already, it doesnt work... I think the reason that it is not working is something to do with getImage(getCodeBase(), "gladiator.gif") , i also tried using the repaint(10) which waited 10 ns before repainting...

Comment: Try using a blocking method to get the image such as `ImageIO.read(...)`. Also, I believe that for a JApplet you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)` not `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

Comment: @hovercraftfullofeels I hope you're not suggesting that they should block then EDT? Cause that's how it reads.  It's also been a long time since I played with appets, but isn't the init & start methods called in the EDT?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes, but he doesn't want to start the applet until the image has been read in and ready to be rendered.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels After some testing, to my surprise, the init and start methods are **NOT** called in the `EDT`.  I should never have taken that for granted :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the applet context to the `drawImage` method, this allows the appet to be notified when the image is loaded and it will repaint itself

```
g2.drawImage(image,100,100,100, 100, this);
```

And, if you're really desperate, call `invalidate()` `repaint()` in the `start` method

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE**

This is the code that I used.  I had no issue with loading the image:

```
public class TestApplet extends JApplet {

    public void init() {

        System.out.println("Init..." + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });

    }

    public void start() {

        System.out.println("Start..." + EventQueue.isDispatchThread());

    }

    public void createGUI() {

        URL documentBase = getDocumentBase();

        System.out.println(documentBase);
        System.out.println(getCodeBase());

//        file:.../build/TestApplet.html
//        file:.../build/classes/        
        Image image = getImage(documentBase, "MT-vol-6-STOP-image-Kogumiko-megatokyo-11434773-1559-1852.jpg");

        System.out.println("image = " + image);

        getContentPane().add(new GUIThing(image));
    }

    public class GUIThing extends JPanel {

        Image image;

        public GUIThing(Image i2) {
            image = i2;
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

            g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        }
    }

}
```

Wow, it's been a long time since I played with applets.  I changed your code from using the code base to the document base it seems to have worked.  I was loading an image of 1559x1852 pixels with little to no delay (locally)

Double check your applet tag in you HTML file as well.  I was using

```
<APPLET codebase="classes" code="stack/TestApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>
```

Through the applet viewer.  Note the code base is different from the document base!!

My image was in the same location as the HTML file

Comment: You could take a look at the ImageObserver API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html this would allow you to respond with repaint once the image is loaded

Comment: I tried overriding updateImage(Image img) with a repaint() but it still doesnt seem to work, can you get this exemple to work??

Comment: +1 for many things, but especially for using an image with `megatokyo` in the name.  :)